# Convert Web Service List of Objects to Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jqplot

I have a .NET web service that is returning a list like so:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"EventTypeSum","EventType":"Carpool","Value":"32.0","Earned":null},{"__type":"EventTypeSum","EventType":"Bus","Value":"4.0","Earned":null},{"__type":"EventTypeSum","EventType":"Bike","Value":"4.5","Earned":null},{"__type":"EventTypeSum","EventType":"Walk","Value":"2.5","Earned":null},{"__type":"EventTypeSum","EventType":"Telework","Value":"9.0","Earned":null},{"__type":"EventTypeSum","EventType":"Alternate Schedule","Value":"3.0","Earned":null}]}
```

I need it in the format

```
[[['Carpool', 32], ['Bus', 4], ['Bike', 4.5], ['Walk', 2.5], ['Telework', 9], ['Alternate Schedule', 3]]]
```

for use in jQuery jqplot.

How can I convert this in my AJAX call?  I've tried several methods and none work.

```
    var ajaxDataRenderer = function (url, plot1, options) {
        var ytdData = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                start: "01-01-" + $("#<%=year_DropDownList.ClientID%>").val()
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d, function (i, data) {
                    ytdData.push(data.EventType);
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return ytdData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ytdData = []`, but never mind.

```
$.each(data.d, function () {
    ytdData.push([data.EventType, data.Value]);
});
```

You have a *triply* nested array (not just double which is what you will get from the above) in your requirements.  I don't see why you would need this, but it would require these changes:

```
ytdData = [[]];

ytdData[0].push
```